# What kind of Ram for IIS sites that use a lot of memory?

Tags: iis-7, memory, dell-poweredge

I have a server where each site in IIS 7.5 stores all of it's settings in memory.
So I tend to eat up a lot of RAM.

I need to order a new server and I was wondering what kind of Memory configuration is the best bang for the buck:

UDIMMs vs RDIMMs
Single Ranked UDIMM vs Dual Ranked UDIMM

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well UDIMMs are a *little* quicker (due to buffer overheads) and often a lot cheaper than RDIMMs but in general you can't have a many UDIMMs in a system as RDIMMs, that's the point of RDIMMs. You often can't get UDIMMs in the sizes you can with RDIMMs too.

So it all depends on how much memory you want in your server really, you've got 16GB already, most UDIMM-configured systems max out at 48GB, whereas many RDIMM-configured systems can have 384GB or more.

Be aware you can't mix UDIMMS and RDIMMS ok.

Answer (score 1):

The fact you are using IIS is irrelevant - you just have a memory hungry config, so want a big chunk of RAM.

Your best bet is to pop over to somewhere like [crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com), and input your server type - it will then spit out various memory options which are compatible with your server and you can pick and choose your price point.

The problem is that pricing varies dramatically so any single answer here will be dated far too rapidly for it to be useful.